# Can you "call in sick" via an email? Is it a metaphor?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, metaphors

> Let's call in sick today for the office

Is this sentence correct? The intention is to take sick leave at work. Is using "call in" a metaphor? Because we usually write an email or send a chat message for informing anything.

Comment: In my country, we very often use a 'telephone' or more shortly a 'phone' to notify a workplace of sick absence. The usual verb for contacting someone by phone is **call**. We add 'in' and say e.g. I called in to say I would be late for work or I called in sick to my work. In my job I am required to use a phone to let my manager know if I am sick.

Comment: Yes, I think you *could* reasonably say ***to call in sick*** is "figurative", since to many if not most native speakers today it's a perfectly acceptable usage even if you only notify your employer by text rather than an actual ***voice call***. Besides which, ***call*** in the sense of ***contact by phone*** is already "metaphoric" - it's not like you're *literally* calling out by voice to get someone's attention.

Comment: Confusingly, [**call out (of work)**](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/how-to-call-out-of-work) is also used. I don't really use it myself, but it seems to be particularly common in situations like retail or hospitality when schedules are irregular. It's a funny quirk that we can use opposite prepositions (in/out) for the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

"Call in sick" is just [an idiomatic expression defined as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+in+sick)

> To inform one's employer that one will be absent due to illness (real or feigned). **The phrase originally referred to calling by phone, but can refer to any form of communication (such as email).**